# Filtering email addresses in an array -php

Tags: php, array-filter

I have a php array containing email addresses as array(email_address1 => name1, email2 => name2) format.

I need to check that emails are valid and I can `foreach` and

```
foreach($arr as $email => $name) { 
   $new = array();
   if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $new[$email] = $name;
  }
return $new;
}
```

Can I achieve the above using array_filter? what would be the syntax??

```
array_filter($emails_arr, 'filter_var') ?? how about FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL parameter?
```

thanks.

Comment: You really should NOT use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL -- it returns invalid for a number of *VALID* email addresses by RFC 3696. You can get a script which doesn't fail @ http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the eMails as array *keys*, you cannot use `array_filter` and `filter_var` together directly. You'd have to write a *callback* function that you can pass to `array_filter` that operates on the array *keys* instead of the *values*; in which case you can just as well stick with your `foreach` solution.

Note that `me@the.foo` and `mary@had.a.little.la.mb` are both considered *valid* by `filter_var`, because it will only test syntax and not semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function filter_email($email) that just calls filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL).

Keep in mind that this check just confirms that the email adress has a valid format, not that it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If possible use DNS / MX validation. Maybe consider using a class for that? A good choice would be  http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.email_address

```
$emails = array(
    'me@the.re' => "user from beyond",
    'lalala' => "Lala user",
    'mary@had.a.little.la.mb' => "Mary with lamb"
);
$validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress(
                 Zend_Validate_Hostname::ALLOW_DNS |
                 Zend_Validate_Hostname::ALLOW_LOCAL,
                 true); // enable DNS checking and lastly enable MX checking
foreach($emails as $email => $name){
    if ($validator->isValid($email)) {
        $validEmails[$email] => $name
    } else {
        foreach ($validator->getMessages() as $message) {
            echo "$message\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Try that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filter_var_array :

```
$result = array_intersect_key($arr, array_fill_keys(filter_var_array(array_keys($arr), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL), ''));
```

[array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) : gets an array which contains all the keys of your input

[filter_var_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php) : filter an array of values

[array_fill_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) : creates an array which keys are the value of the first input array and values are the second parameter

[array_intersect_key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) : returns all values from the first parameter which key correspond to a key from one of the other parameters

Answer (score 0):

This would require all kinds of obscure use of nested functions, like in Arkh's answer. I think you're better off, for maintainability purposes, to just using a loop. The `foreach` is a really great way of adding a little more semantic meaning to code involving iterators.

Comment: Obscure ? These functions are screaming "chain us plz" everytime you check the php doc in the array section.
But yeah, not really maintainable and foreach looks more logic.

Comment: Sure, but all these functions do is mask the behavior of the code, which is a loop. `array_map` is great for quickly prototyping things and writing lean code, but decoding an `array_map` call with several different function return values as its arguments, all manipulating the same data source, isn't readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
return array_filter(array_map('trim', $emails), function ($email) {
           return (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
               ? true
               : false;
        });
```

But as @Gordon wrote

> Note that me@the.foo and mary@had.a.little.la.mb are both considered valid by filter_var, because it will only test syntax and not semantics.

So, you can check the syntax, but you should do some validator check for that. E.g. Zend2/Symfony2 or Laravel Validators?

***You can check also domain of:** `email`

```
    list($name, $emailDomain) = explode('@', $email);
    unset($name);
    if (!checkdnsrr($emailDomain, 'MX')) {
        return false;
    }
```